# The Type TabActivity is deprecated

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I trying to extends my main class from TabActivity ... I wrote the code as bellow :

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    .
    .
    .
.
.
}
```

but I have a worning that the type TabActivity is deprecated !!!!!

[image]

Have any one any Idea about this ???

thank you in advance , Fadel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the official [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

> This class was deprecated in API level 13. New applications should use
>   Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices,
>   you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the
>   Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

See also:

["The type TabActivity is deprecated" For app tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391478/the-type-tabactivity-is-deprecated-for-app-tab)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600207/the-type-tabactivity-is-deprecated-help-to-use-in-older-device

[Android: TabActivity deprecated, use Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382389/android-tabactivity-deprecated-use-fragments)

Or if you have a more specific question, you can add more info.

Comment: Dear @EntryLevelDev ... firstly thank u so much , secondly : Im working in V2 and I runed my application and it worked succufuly ... will it produce problem in the future ????

Comment: Something has been tagged as deprecated programmers are encouraged not to use it. There is no longer a guarantee that it will exist in a future version.

Comment: @Fadel It probably works fine. But if you're gonna make a real production app. It's better to use fragment as the doc suggests.